# Getting column values from CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to print a single column name and the corresponding values for that column in Python from a CSV file using pandas. I am able to print the column names, but when I then try to print just one of the columns with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('pokemon_data.csv')

print(df['name'])
```

I then get these errors:

[image: Errors]

Updated: I see that the error is a "key error" however a key named "Name" should exist as it does when I run:

```
print(df.columns) 

with output:

Index(['#,Name,Type 1,Type 2,HP,Attack,Defense,Sp. Atk,Sp. Def,Speed,Generation,Legendary'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: The column `"name"` does not exist in this DataFrame. You can use `print(df.columns)` to print out which columns *do* exist.

Comment: Post [mre], incl. sample csv file. Also, print the df and post the output.

Answer (score 1):

"KeyError : name" It seems like you don't have a name column.

Answer (score 0):

To extend my comment below your question - your next issue is that the output of `print(df.columns)`, which is `Index(['#,Name,Type 1,Type 2,HP,Attack,Defense,Sp. Atk,Sp. Def,Speed,Generation,Legendary'], dtype='object')`, is indicative that you only have 1 column.

The name of that 1 column is `'#,Name,Type 1,Type 2,HP,Attack,Defense,Sp. Atk,Sp. Def,Speed,Generation,Legendary'`. Maybe there is an issue with your .csv file, or perhaps messing with the `read_csv` settings (see docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)) may help. For example, changing the separator/delimiter to whatever your .csv file is using.